The format of the URI 'Any-Text' is invalid when using dynamic URI for ContentDefinition in Azure B2C
UPDATE:
My use case is:
My client is setting up an Azure B2C Tenant that will respond to 2 different URLs:

https://www.url1.com
https://www.url2.com

They are supposed to be identical (same rules, user journeys, etc) except for the UI. The styling (css, images, page layouts) are stored in different Azure Blob Storages and there is no way I can know the URL in advance. They also provide an external API to get the correct URL based off of the hostname (i.e. if it's url1.com, the blob storage url is blob1.azure.com. Otherwise, it's blob2.azure.com. This is a simplified example, of course. The real URLs are not easy to guess).
I'm supposed to call this API, get the full URL and use it as the ContentDefinition's URI (<LoadUri>), but it seems like I'm not allowed to use a full dynamic URI.
ORIGINAL:
I'm trying use a dynamic URI for a ContentDefinition but I'm getting this error:

Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy "MY POLICY NAME" of tenant "mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com". The format if the URI 'Any-Text' is invalid. The format of the URI 'Any-Text' is invalid.

I'm sending a request to an external API, which returns the URL of the content definition. The response look like this:
{
    "loadUri": "https://my.cdn.com/template.html"
}

The loadUri is then stored in a custom claim and the ContentDefinition uses it like this:
<ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
    <LoadUri>{Claim:loadUri}</LoadUri>
    <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
    <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:2.1.5</DataUri>
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
    </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>

This link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#content-definition tells me that claims can be used to generate dynamic URIs, but all examples make use of scheme + hostname. So, something like this works:
<LoadUri>https://www.my.cdn.com/{Claim:loadUri}</LoadUri>
But my URI is completely dynamic and I don't know the hostname in advance.
I've tried using the schema only (like <LoadUri>https://{Claim:loadUri}</LoadUri>, but I get another error saying:

Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.


Could you please include more details on your current requirement for better understanding?

@Sridevi I've added more details, but in short: The content definition URL is not known in advance and comes from an API. The API returns the full URL, but I'm not allowed to use a full URL. I'm forced to provide a hostname in advance.
